# Verify that all elements of a list are equal

Tags: list, clojure, equality

I have a case, where I need to check if all string elements of a list are equal and I am trying to figure out what the most idiomatic solution would look like. My current approach is, to apply a `map` to the list, checking if every element equals the first and then reducing the result boolean list with '=':

```
(def string-list '("3" "3" "3" "3" "3" "3"))
(reduce = (map #(.equals (first string-list) %) string-list))
```

Obviously, this is not a great solution. Are there more "clojure style" solutions or even a much much simpler approach I am not yet seeing?

Comment: Why not just convert to Set, and check size is 1?

Comment: This would work, but I am not sure if the intention of this code would be clear to other developers at first sight.

Comment: Note that `reduce =` is not just an un-great solution, it's not a solution at all.  Try it on `(1 2 2)`.

Comment: @mavarazy As I mention in a comment on another answer, that would be a bad solution because it doesn't do a good job on potentially-infinite sequences. Even `(cons 1 (repeat 2))` can never be converted to a set, but it can easily be seen that not all elements are the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(apply = string-list)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Worth calling out that this will blow up with an arity exception for an empty list, so you may want to do a non-emptiness check first for safety.

Answer (score 4):

As @Symfrog answered, using `apply` and `=` looks best.

```
(apply = string-list)
```

Perhaps it looks possible to use `distinct` function or `set`, however, these are not a good idea, because these don't work for infinite sequence, though the correct answer will return quickly.

```
;; works for small sequence, however, will not work for infinite sequence like (range)
(= 1 (count (distinct string-list))) ; bad idea
(= 1 (count (into #{} string-list))) ; bad idea
```

Comment: `(= 1 (count (distinct string-list)))` is a bad solution: it never returns for `(range)`, even though the correct answer could be very quickly seen to be `false`.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for the comment. I didn't though that.